# set "constant" after the fact

Tags: java, android

I'm wanting to set a final variable after starting the constant. This works if the variable is not `final`, but that kind of defeats the purpose.

Can I do something *similar* to this?

```
public static final String ASDF = null; 
{
    ASDF = "asdf";
}
```

My situation:

```
public static JSONArray CATEGORIES = null; 
{
    String str = "";
    str += "\"" + FIRST_CATEGORY + "\"";
    try {
        CATEGORIES = new JSONArray("[" + str + "]");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I'm not exactly sure what's going on here, but it works.

```
public static final JSONArray CATEGORIES = new JSONArray() {
    {
        put(FIRST_CATEGORY);
        // etc eg. put(SECOND_CATEGORY);
    }
};
```

Comment: You're creating an _anonymous subclass_.  Perhaps the most-common example of this is how `Listener` subclasses are (often) implemented in Swing.  Also, note that anybody with a reference to `CATEGORIES` can modify it at any time (for everybody) (assuming `put` is not `private`) - this may not be what you want.  You may wish to consider making the instance `private`, then using a copy-getter.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a static initialization block - at least, you can in regular Java SE (I'm assuing android can too):

```
public static final JSONArray CATEGORIES;
static {
    String str = "\"" + FIRST_CATEGORY + "\"";
    try {
        CATEGORIES = new JSONArray("[" + str + "]");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note that you are not first intializing `CATEGORIES` to null, it is left uninitialized until the static block happens.

Although, you're probably going to want to hard-fail if the intialization generates an exception, because otherwise you'll have an improperly initialized variable (serious problems possible).
And, unless the `JSONArray` class is immutable, declaring the instance `final` is ~sorta pointless.

Comment: gah, so close. Yeah, hard fail is no go.

Comment: @Jackson - Then you're going to have to write some sort of detection code, because the state of the instance - both the actual object, and the reference to it -  is undefined (if I'm remembering things correctly).

Comment: I figured out a solution. I'm not sure how or why it works, but it's similar to yours with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

you can choose to not include "= null" on your variable declaration. just make sure that you assign a value to your variable once - be it inside an if-else, a loop, or whatever - the compiler will detect if you're breaking this rule, and won't let your program compile.

```
public static JSONArray CATEGORIES = null; 
{
    String str;
    str += "\"" + FIRST_CATEGORY + "\"";
    try {
        CATEGORIES = new JSONArray("[" + str + "]");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
};
```